# How can I implement `my_class_instance(a, b) = value` operation

Tags: c++

I have a class `Flight` and I need to implement two operations:

```
Flight s;
auto value = s(1, 2);
s(3, 4) = value;
```

I know how to implement first operation:

```
class Flight 
{
public:
  int operator()(int a, int b) {
     return cache.for(a, b).get();
  }
private:
 // cache  
}
```

But I don't know implement second operation. Something like this:

```
void operator()=(int a, int b, int value) {
   cache.for(a, b).set(value);
}
```

Now I have an error `operation is not accessible for` expression like `s(3, 4) = value;`.

How can I implement this operation?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, could you please give me an example, link or words to search for - how can i implement `s(a, b) = value` syntax for set operation?

Comment: Here’s a short description: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op

Comment: @KonradRudolph, thank you! It helps me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `()=` operator.  It is two separate operators - `operator()`, and then `operator=` on the return value of `operator()`.

Since you want to use separate `get()` and `set()` methods inside the cache, you will have to make your `Flight::operator()` return a helper proxy, and then you can implement `proxy::operator int` to call the `get()` method and `proxy::operator=` to call the `set()` method, eg:

```cpp
class Flight 
{
public:
    class Proxy
    {
    private:
        Flight &f;
        int a, b;

    public:
        Proxy(Flight &f, int a, int b) : f(f), a(a), b(b) {}

        operator int() {
            return f.cache.For(a, b).get();
        };

        Proxy& operator=(int value) {
            f.cache.For(a, b).set(value);
            return *this;
        }
    };

    friend class Proxy;

    Proxy operator()(int a, int b) {
        return Proxy{*this, a, b};
    }

private:
    // cache
};
```

Then your example will work as you want:

```cpp
Flight s;
int value = s(1, 2); // <-- important - int, not auto!
s(3, 4) = value;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/cDc0YN)